# Rise or Increase

Tags: meaning-in-context

With English being the second language, I'm trying to learn it. But it's difficult for me to understand usage of synonyms. Could you help me? What should I say:

> the cost of living is rising

or

> the cost of living is increasing

Comment: Both are good, and they mean the same thing. This is one of the problems (and joys) of English -- there are so many ways to say the same thing. You can also say "the cost of living is going up", which is more colloquial (at least, in BrE).

Answer (score 3):

[Rise](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/rise) : to increase in amount, number, level, etc. : to become more

[Increase](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/increase) : to become larger or greater in size, amount, number, etc.

In this context, both "rise" and "increase" are fine.  This also works in different tenses:

> The cost of living rose / increased ...
>
> The cost of living has risen / has increased ...

Or as a [verbal noun](http://www.englishgrammar.org/verbal-nouns/):

> The rising/increasing cost of living

Where you have to be careful is that while *increase* has the generic meaning "to become greater", *rise* specifically means "to move upward", or "to expand outward". So while I can say:

> The balloon was rising into the sky

I *can't* say

> The balloon is *increasing* into the sky.

I can say the balloon's *height* is increasing, or its *size*, but I have to define what i mean.  "Rise" is already defined as an *upward* movement, so it's fine by itself.  Also, I can use *increase* for any direction, even downward:

> The economic forecast is increasingly poor.

So while *rise* and *increase* are synonyms, they aren't *perfect* synonyms.  Few words are.  Even the word [ascend](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/ascend) (to go up, to rise or move toward the sky) which you might *assume* can be used the same as *rise*, has a different nuance:

> They ascended the staircase

implies that they *climbed up* the staircase themselves, while

> They rose up the staircase

implies that they were either carried, or appeared to move as if they were being carried.

In the end you have to pay attention to how native speakers use the words, and copy the patterns as you see them.

Answer (score 1):

The cost of something can be both expressed as a "level" (high/low) and as an amount of individual items (dollars, etc.).  So both will work.  *Rising* probably has a more dramatic/urgent connotation.